# Why can't I get a lock on an InnoDB table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

I have problem with lock table command: `LOCK TABLE v3_cam_date WRITE;` 
the command always running with state:   `"Waiting for table metadata lock"`.

Try to find out which thread was hold the lock on the table v3_cam_date by using command:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES FROM reportingdb 
 LIKE '%v3_cam_date';

Database    Table         In_use    Name_locked

reportingdb v3_cam_date 0   0
```

(In_use=0 => have no any lock on the table).
And I can't get write lock only on the table v3_cam_date while can get write lock on other tables.

Try to SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
return about 30 thread with idle state.

- [Detail List](http://pastebin.com/geANf37e)
- [InnoDB Status](http://pastebin.com/WkfMUWL6)
- MySQL : 5.5.13
- Engine: InnoDB

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

According to the MySQL Documentation on [MetaData Locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/metadata-locking.html)

> If the server acquires metadata locks for a statement that is
>   syntactically valid but fails during execution, it does not release
>   the locks early. Lock release is still deferred to the end of the
>   transaction because the failed statement is written to the binary log
>   and the locks protect log consistency.

[Somone submitted this state as a bug, but the bug report claims it is not a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61935).

Both of these links describe DDL (Data Definition Language) against a table as a contributing factor. What is interesting to keep in mind is that doing something like `TRUNCATE TABLE` is, in reality, DDL. We have to aware of any SQL we run. We may think it is SQL that is part of a transaction when, in fact, it is DDL. [**`TRUNCATE TABLE` is an example of DDL we think is DML**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html). This can cause current transactions to commit and may have unpredictable results when it comes to writing binary log events as the [first link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/metadata-locking.html) states:

> Before MySQL 5.5.3, when a transaction acquired a metadata lock for a
>   table used within a statement, it released the lock at the end of the
>   statement. This approach had the disadvantage that if a DDL statement
>   occurred for a table that was being used by another session in an
>   active transaction, statements could be written to the binary log in
>   the wrong order.